# Azure function locally fails on MacOS

Tags: python, azure, azure-functions

I am following the instructions here on getting started with Azure Functions, using VS Code on MacOS Big Sur (11.6.2)
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-functions/create-first-function-vs-code-python

The local deployment fails with the following errors:

```
[2021-12-21T00:12:34.777Z] Traceback (most recent call last):
[2021-12-21T00:12:34.777Z]   File "/usr/local/Cellar/azure-functions-core-tools@4/4.0.3971/workers/python/3.9/OSX/X64/azure_functions_worker/bindings/shared_memory_data_transfer/file_accessor_unix.py", line 127, in _get_valid_mem_map_dirs
[2021-12-21T00:12:34.777Z]     os.makedirs(dir_path)
[2021-12-21T00:12:34.777Z]   File "/usr/local/Cellar/python@3.9/3.9.9/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.9/lib/python3.9/os.py", line 215, in makedirs
[2021-12-21T00:12:34.777Z]     makedirs(head, exist_ok=exist_ok)
[2021-12-21T00:12:34.778Z]   File "/usr/local/Cellar/python@3.9/3.9.9/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.9/lib/python3.9/os.py", line 225, in makedirs
[2021-12-21T00:12:34.778Z]     mkdir(name, mode)
```

Comment: You cut of the traceback before it gets interesting.

Answer (score 0):

We have reproduced the same from our end following the same [Document](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-functions/create-first-function-vs-code-python) and found everything was working well. You need to navigate to the highlighted url mentioned in the below image which you'll be finding in the console, in order to check if Azure functions are working.

[image]

The errors that you were mentioning in the question are the tracebacks which you'll be receiving while running Azure Functions.

[image]

Here is the output:

[image]